# Android GCM: sendRegistrationIdToBackend syntax error on token void

Tags: android, syntax-error, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the android GCM tutorial provided by google, and I get the following errors:

on the line:

```
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
  // Your implementation here.

}
```

Syntax error on Token "Void", @ expected.

Syntax error insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader.

Using, compiler 1.6

Thank you so much.

The entire function:

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
      // Your implementation here.

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, put all the code where the function is in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to close the `registerInBackground()` method.

Add `}` after `}.execute(null, null, null);`

Another way to look at it is that you put `private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {}` inside the `registerInBackground()` method, which is wrong.